# Using Apache Cassandra with a java application build over Java 11?

Tags: java, cassandra, java-11

Newbie to Cassandra. I understand current versions of Cassandra do not support Java 11.
Can you run Cassandra using Java 8 and access the instance with a Java application built over and running on Java 11?

If so, how can it be done? Can you show a simple example?

I'm looking to build a POC on my laptop for an L&L.
Thanks in advance for any and all assistance.

Comment: The JDK versions of the Cassandra cluster and the application are mutually exclusive.  Have you tried building a Java 11 app and connecting to Cassandra?  If so, what errors are you seeing?

Comment: I've brought up an instance of Cassandra under java 8. But haven't built the POC app just yet. Our current business environment is running 11 so I will be building it using 11. I just wasn't sure if having Java_Home pointed to 8 so I can run the Cassandra Instance. Running the POC from inside Intellij under 11. Do you know of any issues going that route?

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra and the application connecting to it run on different JVMs, so their versions are independent. Since the app will use [a driver](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/drivers.html#java), you need to find one that works on Java 11. Either just try it out or search the projects' documentation for supported Java versions.

Looks like DataStax' driver [is build on 9 to 14](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/4.x/Jenkinsfile#L294), so I would give that one a try.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Will give it a try.